# Como mostrar o resultado do Controller na View c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, http, post

Gostaria como posso mostrar meu resultado que esta no metodo do controller na View.

EX:
Controller:

```
public class SMSTarifado
{
    public int QtdTarifados { get; set; }
    public int QtdEnviados { get; set; }
    public int QtdRespondidos { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {


         ViewBag.tarifados  = "1"
         ViewBag.enviados   = "1"
         ViewBag.respondidos= "1"


        return View();
    }




    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string campanhaSelecionada2, string mesAno)
    {
        var campanhaSelecionada = campanhaSelecionada2;
        var mesAnoSelecionado = mesAno.Split('/');



        var result = banco.Database.SqlQuery<SMSTarifado>("SP_CARREGA_GRAFICO_SMS_TARIFADOS @param1, @param2, @param3 ", new SqlParameter("@param1", Convert.ToInt32(campanhaSelecionada)), new SqlParameter("@param2", Convert.ToInt32(mesAnoSelecionado[0])), new SqlParameter("@param3", Convert.ToInt32(mesAnoSelecionado[1]))).ToList();


        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            ViewBag.tarifados   = Convert.ToString(item.QtdTarifados);
            ViewBag.enviados    = Convert.ToString(item.QtdEnviados);
            ViewBag.respondidos = Convert.ToString(item.QtdRespondidos);
        }


        ListaCampanhas();
        return View();        

    }
```

JQUERY:

```
var campanhaSelecionada2;
campanhaSelecionada2 = $("#campanhaSMSTarifados option:selected").val();
$("#campanhaSMSTarifados").change(function () {
    campanhaSelecionada2 = $("#campanhaSMSTarifados option:selected").val();
});

var mesAno;
mesAno = $("#mesAno option:selected").val();
$("#mesAno").change(function () {
    mesAno = $("#mesAno option:selected").text();
});



$("#btnBuscar").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/SMSTarifados/Index",
        data: { campanhaSelecionada2: campanhaSelecionada2,mesAno:mesAno},
    });
});
```

IMG DE EXPLICAÇÃO:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após eu escolher uma campanha a data e ano e clico em buscar...
Ele ira fazer uma chamada post pelo ajax para que traga os resultados e mostrada cada qual no seu lugar como esta o verde !

Porém atualmente não aparece nada no lugar de onde tem que ser mostrado o resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Alguns pontos que podem ser observados:

1) Evite a utilização de ViewBag. Crie um objeto e passe seu Model para a View.

2) Os valores que você passa do controller para a view vc deve setar no JS.
Se estiver passando no Model, você pode colocar @Model.NomeDaVariavel

3) Procure criar uma responsabilidade única para cada método. Não faça muita coisa dentro de um método. Existem padrões que é altamente aconselhado seguir para tornar o código de fácil manutenção no futuro.

4) Coloque os Name e Id no form idênticos e tenha certeza que o JS está chamando o id correto.